# How to predict and add values to original dataset

Tags: r, mgcv, timetk

I have a large dataset that I need to predict some values for. I have this small
reproducible example below. I would like to predict for a few years ahead using
either gam or glm, however, I can't wrap my head around it since I don't  have
statistics background. Could some one guide me on how to predict and add the predicted
values to my original dataset?

```
library(mgcv)
library(tidyverse)
m <- structure(list(year = c(2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007), month = c("August", "August", "September", "September", 
"October", "October", "November", "November", "December", "August", 
"August", "September", "September", "October", "October", "November", 
"November", "December", "August", "August", "September", "October", 
"October", "November", "November", "December", "August", "August", 
"September", "September", "October"), date = structure(c(12265, 
12281, 12296, 12311, 12326, 12342, 12357, 12372, 12387, 12631, 
12647, 12662, 12677, 12692, 12708, 12723, 12738, 12753, 12996, 
13012, 13027, 13422, 13438, 13453, 13468, 13483, 13726, 13742, 
13757, 13772, 13787), class = "Date"), turb = c(12.5, 11.8, 8.9, 
6.2, 5.1, 3.4, -0.1, 0, -0.1, 12.5, 10.4, 8.6, 6.1, 4.7, 1.4, 
0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 12.5, 11, 8, 4.4, 1.1, 0.5, -0.2, -0.2, 12.5, 
11.7, 10, 5.9, 3.6)), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

m$date <- as.numeric(m$date)
mod1 <- gam(turb ~ s(date), data = m)
summary(mod1)

#How can I predict 3 more years (to 2010) and have those predictions
#added to the bottom of the original dataset(m)?
```

Comment: Check out the `predict` function

Comment: You're hoping to predict `date` based on the value of `turb`, or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm wrong, but I think you're trying to predict `turb` based on the smoothed `date`. If so, then

```r
m$datenum <- as.numeric(m$date) # just to keep `date` unchanged
mod1 <- mgcv::gam(turb ~ s(datenum), data = m)
new_m <- tibble(date = c(outer(max(m$date) %m+% months(0:36), c(0, 15), `+`))[-1]) %>%
  mutate(datenum = as.numeric(date))
new_m
# # A tibble: 73 × 2
#    date       datenum
#    <date>       <dbl>
#  1 2007-11-01   13818
#  2 2007-12-01   13848
#  3 2008-01-01   13879
#  4 2008-02-01   13910
#  5 2008-03-01   13939
#  6 2008-04-01   13970
#  7 2008-05-01   14000
#  8 2008-06-01   14031
#  9 2008-07-01   14061
# 10 2008-08-01   14092
# # ℹ 63 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
predict(mod1, newdata = new_m)
#           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10          11          12          13 
#   -1.246062   -6.392131  -11.709736  -17.027341  -22.001874  -27.319479  -32.465548  -37.783153  -42.929222  -48.246827  -53.564432  -58.710501  -64.028106 
#          14          15          16          17          18          19          20          21          22          23          24          25          26 
#  -69.174175  -74.491780  -79.809385  -84.612383  -89.929987  -95.076057 -100.393661 -105.539731 -110.857335 -116.174940 -121.321010 -126.638614 -131.784684 
#          27          28          29          30          31          32          33          34          35          36          37          38          39 
# -137.102288 -142.419893 -147.222891 -152.540496 -157.686565 -163.004170 -168.150239 -173.467844 -178.785449 -183.931518    1.498509   -3.819096   -8.965165 
#          40          41          42          43          44          45          46          47          48          49          50          51          52 
#  -14.282770  -19.600375  -24.574909  -29.892514  -35.038583  -40.356188  -45.502257  -50.819862  -56.137466  -61.283536  -66.601140  -71.747210  -77.064814 
#          53          54          55          56          57          58          59          60          61          62          63          64          65 
#  -82.382419  -87.185417  -92.503022  -97.649091 -102.966696 -108.112765 -113.430370 -118.747975 -123.894044 -129.211649 -134.357718 -139.675323 -144.992928 
#          66          67          68          69          70          71          72          73 
# -149.795926 -155.113531 -160.259600 -165.577205 -170.723274 -176.040879 -181.358483 -186.504553
```

This can be combined with the original data with

```r
combined <- new_m %>%
  mutate(turb = predict(mod1, newdata = cur_data()), year = as.integer(format(date, format="%Y")), month = format(date, format = "%B")) %>%
  bind_rows(m) %>%
  arrange(date)
combined
# # A tibble: 104 × 5
#    date       datenum      turb  year month    
#    <date>       <dbl> <dbl[1d]> <dbl> <chr>    
#  1 2003-08-01   12265      12.5  2003 August   
#  2 2003-08-17   12281      11.8  2003 August   
#  3 2003-09-01   12296       8.9  2003 September
#  4 2003-09-16   12311       6.2  2003 September
#  5 2003-10-01   12326       5.1  2003 October  
#  6 2003-10-17   12342       3.4  2003 October  
#  7 2003-11-01   12357      -0.1  2003 November 
#  8 2003-11-16   12372       0    2003 November 
#  9 2003-12-01   12387      -0.1  2003 December 
# 10 2004-08-01   12631      12.5  2004 August   
# # ℹ 94 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
tail(combined)
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   date       datenum      turb  year month    
#   <date>       <dbl> <dbl[1d]> <dbl> <chr>    
# 1 2010-08-01   14822     -173.  2010 August   
# 2 2010-08-16   14837     -176.  2010 August   
# 3 2010-09-01   14853     -179.  2010 September
# 4 2010-09-16   14868     -181.  2010 September
# 5 2010-10-01   14883     -184.  2010 October  
# 6 2010-10-16   14898     -187.  2010 October
```

Comment: I wonder why those predictions are exponentialy going negative to `-187` @r2evans.  My smallest turb value is `-0.2` and my largest is `12.5`.

Comment: My answer is demonstrating the use of `predict(mod1, newdata=)`. I'm not advising on the usability of that GAM with your data. *"Prediction is very difficult, especially if it’s about the future"* (https://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/10/20/no-predict/). If you want that, I suggest you migrate the question to [stats.se] where the theory of models is more appropriate.

Comment: You're trying to predict `turb` as a function of `date`, which, by the look of your original example, is not the case. You need to find the appropriate predictor(s) for `turb` in the original data set.

Comment: @Salvador, I think the answer addresses your question *"predict more 3 more years and have those predictions added to the bottom of the original dataset"*. Regardless of the applicability of your actual model formulation, the mechanism is going to remain the same. Do you agree, or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to predict `turb`. @r2evans, your answer addresses the question properly. However, I was assuming that I would get values somewhat close to -0.2 and 12.5 instead of getting those huge differences.

Comment: Asking how to better model that is likely more appropriate on [stats.se]. I don't have recent experience with GAMs so I don't have any modeling advice at this time.

Comment: The default smooth will linearly extrapolate when forecasting outside the range of the data. This is unlikely to yield good predictions. You might like to try the MVGAM package or our MRFtools package (only on GitHub) to use a RW1 as the trend

Comment: Hi @GavinSimpson Is there any vignettes in github for either of these packages.

Comment: Look for yourself, Salvador: https://github.com/nicholasjclark/mvgam (yes) and https://github.com/eric-pedersen/MRFtools (no), I believe ... inferring (neither the author nor a user of them).